# how remove '[ ] -' from pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
1990    [230 000 - 360 000]
1991    [240 000 - 390 000]
1992    [250 000 - 410 000]
1993    [260 000 - 430 000]
1994    [270 000 - 440 000]
1995    [280 000 - 460 000]
```

How do I remove the '[ ] -' from the column?
And or split the two values into two new columns?

```
import pandas as pd


def transpose_csv(in_file='E:\WHO\People living with HIV_People living with HIV (all ages).csv',
                  out_file='E:\WHO\People living with HIV.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(in_file, index_col='Country').transpose()
    df.to_csv(out_file)


def clean_csv(in_file='E:\WHO\People living with HIV.csv', out_file='E:\WHO\PeoplelivingwithHIV.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(in_file, encoding='latin-1')
    df1 = df['Brazil'].str.strip('[]').str.split('-', expand=True)
    df1.to_csv(out_file)


def concat(in_file='E:\WHO\PeoplelivingwithHIV.csv', out_file='E:\WHO\PeoplelivingwithHIVCONCAT.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
    concat_df = pd.concat([df[0]], axes=1)
    concat_df.to_csv(out_file)


transpose_csv()
clean_csv()
concat()
```

for df[0] gives:
KeyError: 0
/for df.columns gives:
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Comment: You should post your expected results because your requirements can be read in two different ways. Would the final result have 3 columns or 4 columns? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for that:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
      0                    1
0  1990  [230 000 - 360 000]
1  1991  [240 000 - 390 000]
2  1992  [250 000 - 410 000]
3  1993  [260 000 - 430 000]
4  1994  [270 000 - 440 000]
5  1995  [280 000 - 460 000]


In [13]: df[1].str.strip('[]').str.split('-', expand=True)
Out[13]: 
          0         1
0  230 000    360 000
1  240 000    390 000
2  250 000    410 000
3  260 000    430 000
4  270 000    440 000
5  280 000    460 000
```

Or if you want to have with your original column you could use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [17]: pd.concat([df[0],res], axis=1)
Out[17]: 
      0         0         1
0  1990  230 000    360 000
1  1991  240 000    390 000
2  1992  250 000    410 000
3  1993  260 000    430 000
4  1994  270 000    440 000
5  1995  280 000    460 000
```

**EDIT**

For your code you need to change your `concat` function because [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) joining **`2`** dataframes but you pass only 1, you should modify that as:

```
def concat(in_file1='E:\WHO\People living with HIV.csv', in_file2='E:\WHO\PeoplelivingwithHIV.csv', out_file='E:\WHO\PeoplelivingwithHIVCONCAT.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(in_file1)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(in_file2)
    concat_df = pd.concat([df, df1, axis=1)
    concat_df.to_csv(out_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. got the str.strip, and str.split to work after realizing you have to specify a 'col' for it to work on a DataFrame,  can't get the concat to work, concat_df = pd.concat([df['0']], axis=1) the "res" shows up as an error, what exactly does it do?

Comment: @JessePhilips I think you've got an error because your `df['0']` should be `df[0]` without quotes because it's a number (if you're using columns names from the answer. If not could you post you `df.columns` output? `pd.concat` joining dataframes, with `axis=1` it's added second dataframe as columns

Comment: @JessePhilips try edited version. `pd.concat` need two or more dataframe and it has `axis` argument not `axes`. I added link in the answer.